# How to Rename "Request new password" link?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

We want to rename the "Request new password" text on a Drupal's login page to some custom text.

In the user.module file, I see that this text is hard coded

```
if (variable_get('user_register', 1)) {
    $items[] = l(t('Create new account'), 'user/register', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Create a new user account.'))));
  }
  $items[] = l(t('Request new password'), 'user/password', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Request new password via e-mail.'))));
  $form['links'] = array('#value' => theme('item_list', $items));
```

Is there any other way of renaming this text rather than modifying the Drupal core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module?

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the
>   Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of
>   overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need
>   a few easy text changes.

Comment: I tried solution below because I wanted to change the text for registering but it didn't work for me in D7.  Didn't really want to install another module but I found String Overrides to be a great module and used it to change a bunch of strings.  Awesome module!

Answer (score 12):

The String Overrides module is a good suggestion if you have many strings, or need to constantly alter them, but you can also achieve this by editing the string overrides section of your [settings.php file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites--default--default.settings.php/6/source).

Simply uncomment the section so it looks like this:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'] = array(
  'Request new password' => 'MY CUSTOM TEXT FOR A NEW PASSWORD',
);
```

Comment: I like this solution better than installing a new module just for this one task!

Comment: Never realised that this was an option before. It's a much nicer approach than installing yet another module. Unless of course you want to allow users to be able to define the new text from within the UI.

Comment: Code above is for D6. For D7 use the additional empty bracket like so:

$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array()

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this in Drupal 7 but it wasn't quite right. It needs an extra [''] bit added. This works:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Request new password' => 'MY CUSTOM TEXT FOR A NEW PASSWORD',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two more ways of doing it:

- Install the [iTweak Login module](https://www.drupal.org/project/itweak_login)
- In a custom module, implement hook_menu_alter() like this:

Use your module name instead of 'mymodulename':

```
/*
 * Implements hook_menu_alter(). Change link text of 'Request new password' link.
 */
function mymodulename_menu_alter(&$items) {
      $items['user/password']['title'] = t('Reset password');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in `template.php` of your theme, solution more flexible for my purpose (*I wanted the text in French and English side by side*):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
 */
function YOURTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {
    //Modify the User Login Block Form
    case 'user_login_block':     
      $item = array(); 
      $items[] = l( t('Request new password') . ' |  <span class="en">' . t('Request new password', array(), array('langcode' => 'en')) . '</span>', 'user/password', array('html' => TRUE) ); 

      $form['links']['#markup'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));

    break;
  }
}
```

Originally inspired by [Geoff Hankerson](https://web.archive.org/web/20120826023308/http://geoffhankerson.com:80/node/180). Thanks to him.